# Interpretation of the Linear Algebra solution?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm learning Linear Algebra and am using Gilbert Strang Introduction to Linear Algebra 5.
During my studies in chapter 2.4, I have come across a problem:

[image]

After solving 32, I came up with the right answer of
$$I = 
\begin{bmatrix}
Ax_1 & Ax_2 & Ax_3\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I represents Identity matrix.

Now, the problem comes with exercise 2, because as I had interpreted it:
$$A\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
3 & 3 & 3\\
5 & 5 & 5\\
8 & 8 & 8
\end{bmatrix}$$

However, the result is

[image]

From that I see that:

$$A^{-1}x=b$$

Given the above information. But, how is that at all connected to the equation Ax = b and the question?
What am I missing?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $X$ be (like in Question 32) the $3\times3$ matrix $\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 & x_2 & x_3
\end{bmatrix}.$ You are right in writing $I = 
\begin{bmatrix}
Ax_1 & Ax_2 & Ax_3\\
\end{bmatrix}.$ This is equivalent to $I=AX,$ hence to $A^{-1}=X.$

In Question 33, you are asked to solve $Ax=b,$ which is equivalent to $x=A^{-1}b$ (not $A^{-1}x=b$), i.e. to $x=Xb,$ i.e. $x=3x_1+5x_2+8x_3.$

The "challenge problem" does not use $b.$ It consists in computing $A,$ knowing $A^{-1}=X=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}.$ By the result of Question 32, you can find the three columns $y_1,y_2,y_3$ of $A=X^{-1}$ by solving $Xy_1=\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
0\\
0
\end{bmatrix},$ $Xy_2=\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
1\\
0
\end{bmatrix},$ $Xy_3=\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
0\\
1
\end{bmatrix}.$

Comment: If I understand correctly than when you wrote x = Xb, you meant A^-1 = X, or am I missing something? Why is that the case? How do we know that A^-1 = X = [x1  x2  x3]?

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that this is what we are using, it makes sense when specified.